# Generate multiple sets of random, non-overlapping intervals within a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, random, intervals

Within a specific integer range `[a, b]` I would like to generate `n` lists, each consisting of `z` non-overlapping, random intervals with a minimum interval width of `w`. The non-overlap condition is to be understood within a single such list.

Example for `a=0, b=100, n=4, z=3, w=5`:

```
1. [ [1, 17], [57, 83], [89, 98] ]
2. [ [5, 23], [42, 49], [60, 78] ]
3. [ [70, 76], [80, 89], [93, 99] ]
4. [ [20, 62], [67, 81], [82, 93] ]
```

At the moment I use `numpy.linspace` to return evenly spaced values over the `[a,b]`
 interval for the left interval boundaries, then introduce a small random variation for each of these values.
 Within two such boundaries I then try to place the right interval boundaries while respecting the minimal width requirement. However, my approach is very computationally expensive.

What is the most efficient way of achieving my goal in Python?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to define the right boundaries (between `w` and the space to the start of the next interval) and *then* add the variation, since you'll know the limit of how much to add w/ introducing overlap?

Comment: Or better yet: choose your interval sizes first, then place them in order, randomly taking from the unused space for what goes in between.

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you for the good suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a suggested algorithm:

1. Generate `z` non-negative integers (integers 0 or greater) with a sum of `((b-a)+1) - z*w`. I have written [pseudocode](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Random_Integers_with_a_Given_Positive_Sum) for this algorithm based on Smith and Tromble's "Sampling Uniformly from the Unit Simplex".
2. Add `w` to each number generated this way. This results in the sizes of `z` contiguous candidate intervals.
3. Generate a random subinterval with minimum length `w` inside each candidate interval. These subintervals are the actual output of the algorithm. Each subinterval is shifted accordingly by `a` and the start of its candidate interval.

Comment: Does this guarantee that `a` will always start the first interval?  Or that `a`+1 will?

Answer (score 2):

### Approach 1 - Naive random generation

This is an inefficient but simple approach - take `z*2` random integers from `range(a, b)`, sorted them, pair them up, and check if the intervals are all greater than or equal to `w`. Repeat this `n` times.

Note that this will be inefficient when `z*w` is close to `len(range(a, b))`. I did consider mitigating this by adding a helper function to generate a random `nth` interval that would allow the remaining `z-n` intervals to be created - by selecting indexes from `range(a, b-w*(z-n))`, but that runs into the problem that the intervals chosen first will be biased towards being longer.

**Code:**

```
def list_to_pairs(l):
    return [l[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]

def f(z, w, a, b):
    intervals = [(0,0)]
    while not all(x[1]-x[0] >= w for x in intervals):
        intervals = list_to_pairs(sorted(random.sample(range(a, b), z*2)))
    return intervals

def get_lists(n, z, w, a, b):
    return [f(z, w, a, b) for _ in range(n)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> get_lists(4, 3, 5, 0, 100)
[[[0, 17], [22, 46], [62, 98]],
 [[10, 32], [61, 66], [72, 81]],
 [[2, 31], [63, 68], [77, 87]],
 [[5, 20], [34, 55], [58, 86]]]
```

### Approach 2

@Peter O. outlined a [better algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171898/12366110) that does not rely on randomly picking intervals which I have coded up below with a few minor logic changes.

**Code:**

```
def positive_integers_with_sum(n, total):
    ls = [0]
    rv = []
    while len(ls) < n:
        c = random.randint(0, total)
        ls.append(c)
    ls = sorted(ls)
    ls.append(total)
    for i in range(1, len(ls)):
        rv.append(ls[i] - ls[i-1])
    return rv

def f(z, w, a, b):
    rv = []
    indices = [x+w for x in positive_integers_with_sum(z, (b-a)-z*w)]
    start = a
    for i in indices:
        i_start = random.randint(start, i+start-w)
        i_end = random.randint(max(i_start+w, i+start-w), i+start)
        rv.append([i_start, i_end - 1])
        start+=i
    return rv

def get_lists(n, z, w, a, b):
    return [f(z, w, a, b) for _ in range(n)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> get_lists(5, 3, 5, 0, 15)
[[[0, 4], [5, 9], [10, 14]],
 [[0, 4], [5, 9], [10, 14]],
 [[0, 4], [5, 9], [10, 14]],
 [[0, 4], [5, 9], [10, 14]],
 [[0, 4], [5, 9], [10, 14]]]

>>> get_lists(4, 3, 5, 0, 100)
[[[45, 72], [74, 79], [92, 97]],
 [[18, 23], [39, 44], [77, 97]],
 [[12, 31], [37, 53], [83, 95]],
 [[13, 46], [62, 87], [94, 100]]]
```

**Interval Average Sizes:**

```
rv = [[],[],[]]

for i in range(100000):
    t = f(3,5,0,100)
    for i in range(3):
        rv[i].append(abs(t[i][1] - t[i][0]))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> np.mean(rv, axis=1)
array([16.10771, 16.35467, 16.21329])
```

Answer (score 0):

One of variants for one set of intervals (others are generated in the same manner). Simple but not very effective:
1. generate a set of z values between a and b. In your case it's [x1, x2, x3] (sorted ascending)
2. Transform it into list of intervals: [[x1, x1], [x2, x2], [x3, x3]]
3. Looping by every interval: if its lower border is 1 greater than upper border of previous interval - increase its upper border. Else if its upper border is 1 lesser than lower border of next interval - decrease its lower interval. If none of this coindtions is met - spread your interval in any side. If both are met - oops, bad luck, try again from point 1.
4. Repeat step 3 until all intervals are minimum W wide, and some (random number) times after

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that constructs the intervals such that they have to meet the specifications (so it never needs to "keep picking random values until you get lucky"):

```
from random import randint
def one_list( a, b, z, w ):
    # How many numbers we have to work with
    nums = b - a - 1 
    # Minimum number of values that will be in some interval
    used = w*z
    # Number of additional values in some interval
    extra = randint( 0, nums - used )
    # Number of values not in any interval
    unused = nums - used - extra
    ans = []
    for _ in range(z):
        # How many values to skip over
        skip = randint(0,unused)
        a += skip
        unused -= skip
        # How many more than minimum to put in next interval
        plus = randint(0,extra)
        ans.append([a,a+w-1+plus])
        a += (w+plus)
        extra -= plus
    return ans
```

Comment: This approach falls into the pitfall that I was trying to avoid by randomly generating intervals - the average size of the intervals is skewed such that earlier intervals will be larger. Over `100000` tests using the example in the OP, the average sizes of the generated intervals were ~ `[25.05, 14.53, 9.24]`.

Comment: Adjust random number generators to taste.